# Ensure transactions all complete on SHUTDOWN hook...sample code check

Tags: c

I actually asked a similar question earlier at [Correct way to shutdown C application to ensure CRITICAL sections completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963336/correct-way-to-shutdown-c-application-to-ensure-critical-sections-completed) but wanted to start fresh and ask is anyone can see and FUNDAMENTAL issues with the following code.

I essentially whipped up a proof of concept, and it goes like this:

- Main application launches a thread that needs to "process messages in a transaction"
- When the user hits CTRL-C I need the application to run elegantly until the current thread transaction is complete

NOTE: Callbacks from the thread into the MAIN app is ESSENTIAL and I would like to know if this is "bad programming practice"....

The code is working from the output, here is a sample:

```
lynton@lynton ~/Desktop/ThreadTest $ ./main
Main program started
In thread testMainLoop
Transaction started in spawned thread
onBeginTransaction in main thread
onMessageArrived in main thread
onCommitTransaction in main thread
Transaction ended in spawned thread
Transaction started in spawned thread
onBeginTransaction in main thread
onMessageArrived in main thread
onCommitTransaction in main thread
Transaction ended in spawned thread
Transaction started in spawned thread
onBeginTransaction in main thread
onMessageArrived in main thread
onCommitTransaction in main thread
Transaction ended in spawned thread
^CIn shutdown hook...
Thread still running
listenForMessages loop completed in spawned thread
In onProcessingComplete in main thread
Exciting testMainLoop
All thread transactions complete
Main program exiting
lynton@lynton ~/Desktop/ThreadTest $
```

In the above you can see that the shutdown hook is initiated and the application ends gracefully...

The basis test code is as follows:

PLEASE take special note of the "(*onProcessingCompleteCallbackFunc)(TRUE);" call from the thread to the main application to say to the main application that the thread is 100% complete. The pthread_join did not seem to work as I needed it to here....

NOTE: The following is the SHARED LIB (libwmq_sender.so) that I created that is used by the main application.

wmq_sender.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TRUE 0
#define FALSE 1 

int wmq_sender_start();
int wmq_sender_stop();
void wmq_sender_registerOnBeginTransactionCallback(int (*callbackFunc)(char *tid));
void wmq_sender_registerOnCommitTransactionCallback(int (*callbackFunc)(char *tid));
void wmq_sender_registerOnMessageArrivedCallback(int (*callbackFunc)(char *tid, char *buffer, int size));
void wmq_sender_registerOnProcessingCompleteCallback(void (*callbackFunc)(int completeFlag));
int listenForMessages();

int (*onBeginTransactionCallbackFunc)(char *tid);
int (*onCommitTransactionCallbackFunc)(char *tid);
int (*onRollbackTransactionCallbackFunc)(char *tid);
int (*onMessageArrivedCallbackFunc)(char *tid, char *buffer, int size);
void (*onProcessingCompleteCallbackFunc)(int completeFlag);

int running;
int rc;
int transactionRunning;
```

wmq_sender.c

```
#include "wmq_sender.h"

int listenForMessages(){
    char *uuid = NULL;; 
    char *buffer = NULL;
    uuid = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(uuid, "1234567891");
    buffer = malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(buffer, "test_buffer");

    while(running == TRUE){
        printf("Transaction started in spawned thread\n");
        transactionRunning = TRUE;
        (*onBeginTransactionCallbackFunc)(uuid);
        (*onMessageArrivedCallbackFunc)(uuid, buffer, 11);
        (*onCommitTransactionCallbackFunc)(uuid);
        transactionRunning = FALSE;
        printf("Transaction ended in spawned thread\n");
        sleep(2);
    }   
    printf("listenForMessages loop completed in spawned thread\n");
    free(uuid);
    free(buffer);
    (*onProcessingCompleteCallbackFunc)(TRUE);
    return 0;
}

int wmq_sender_start(){ 
    return listenForMessages();
}

int wmq_sender_stop(){
    running = FALSE;
    return 0;
}

void wmq_sender_registerOnBeginTransactionCallback(int (*callbackFunc)(char *tid)){
    onBeginTransactionCallbackFunc = callbackFunc;
}
void wmq_sender_registerOnCommitTransactionCallback(int (*callbackFunc)(char *tid)){
    onCommitTransactionCallbackFunc = callbackFunc;
}
void wmq_sender_registerOnMessageArrivedCallback(int (*callbackFunc)(char *tid, char *buffer, int size)){
    onMessageArrivedCallbackFunc = callbackFunc;
}
void wmq_sender_registerOnProcessingCompleteCallback(void (*callbackFunc)(int completeFlag)){
    onProcessingCompleteCallbackFunc = callbackFunc;
}
```

The following is the MAIN application that spawns the thread and shuts down gracefully etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "wmq_sender.h"

#define TRUE 0
#define FALSE 1

void *testMainLoop(void *arg);
void shutdownHook(int sig);
int main(int argc, char * argv[]);
int onBeginTransaction(char *tid);
int onCommitTransaction(char *tid);
int onMessageArrived(char *tid, char *buffer, int size);
void onProcessingComplete(int completeFlag);

pthread_t testThread;
int threadRunning;
int rc;

void *testMainLoop(void *arg){
    printf("In thread testMainLoop\n");
    wmq_sender_registerOnBeginTransactionCallback(onBeginTransaction);
    wmq_sender_registerOnCommitTransactionCallback(onCommitTransaction);
    wmq_sender_registerOnMessageArrivedCallback(onMessageArrived);
    wmq_sender_registerOnProcessingCompleteCallback(onProcessingComplete);
    threadRunning = TRUE;
    rc = wmq_sender_start();
    printf("Exciting testMainLoop\n");
}

void shutdownHook(int sig){
    printf("In shutdown hook...\n");
    rc = wmq_sender_stop();
    while(threadRunning == TRUE){
        printf("Thread still running\n");
        sleep(2);
    }
    printf("All thread transactions complete\n");
}

void onProcessingComplete(int completeFlag){
    printf("In onProcessingComplete in main thread\n");
    threadRunning = FALSE;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    (void) signal(SIGINT, shutdownHook);
    printf("Main program started\n");
    rc = pthread_create(&testThread, NULL, testMainLoop, (void *)argv);
    pthread_join(testThread, NULL);
    printf("Main program exiting\n");
    return 0;
}

int onBeginTransaction(char *tid){
    printf("onBeginTransaction in main thread\n");
    return 0;
}
int onCommitTransaction(char *tid){
    printf("onCommitTransaction in main thread\n");
    return 0;
}
int onMessageArrived(char *tid, char *buffer, int size){
    printf("onMessageArrived in main thread\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling on my test machine is:

```
gcc -m64 -Wall -g -I./ -c ./main.c -o ./main.o
gcc -m64 -o ./main ./main.o -L./ -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lpthread -lwmq_sender

gcc -m64 -Wall -g -c -I./ -I/usr/local/include/ -fPIC ./wmq_sender.c -o ./wmq_sender.o
gcc -shared -o ./libwmq_sender.so ./wmq_sender.o

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/lynton/Desktop/ThreadTest"
```

Do you see anything wrong with the way that I use CALLBACKS to tell the main application that the thread is complete etc?

Any help or advise would be great appreciated ;-)

Thanks

Lynton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do realise that your callback functions are actually running on the thread don't you?  As far as I can see, your main thread just creates another thread which does everything and then waits for it to finish.  I don't see any point in creating the second thread at the moment.

Anyway, the other horrible problem you have is that your signal handler calls `printf` and `sleep`.  I'm pretty sure `printf` is not safe to call in a signal handler and neither is `sleep`.  Really all it should do is set a flag to say "terminating" and then return.

According to the C99 standard, you can't reliably assign to any static variable that isn't declared `volatile sig_atomic_t` or call any standard library function except `abort()`, `_Exit()` or `signal()` and the last with the same signal number that you received.